# Perl.cgi soap request HTTP ERROR 411

Tags: apache-httpd, perl, cgi

I'm trying to learn SoapUI, but when running the code below I'm getting **HTTP ERROR 411**
all files are in /var/www/html/ not sure what's the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

  SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI   
    -> dispatch_to('Demo')     
    -> handle;

  package Demo;

  sub hi 
  {                     
    return "hello, world";     
  }

  sub bye 
  {                    
    return "goodbye, cruel world";
  }
```

**Directives**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
AllowOverride None
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

- CentOS 6.8
- Appache: Apache/2.2.15
- Perl: v5.10.1
- Client: HTTP Browser

Comment: That's a client error. What client are you using?

Comment: Can you show me, how to find that ?

Comment: currently I'm using Chrome, I really need to start small, before using SmartBear...

Answer (score 0):

411 is a client error "Length Required". It means the request doesn't contain this field. You need to set the request correctly. Assuming you're using SoapUI as the client (the application that calls the server), you need to set the **request headers** there.

Consult this for example: https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/teststep-reference/http-request/headers.html

Comment: Please is there anyway, to test that in a basic browser first.

Comment: @Driven Just use the browser. I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: yep!! this is exactly what I did and I got 411

Comment: @Driven Then check in the developers tools (or whatever that's called in your browser) what headers you're sending to the server.

Comment: please can you elaborate a little bit more on that. all I did was to put the code in a script.cgi and call the file through the browser: http://Palmcity.net/script.cgi

Comment: @Driven You need to learn these terms to work with CGIs and HTTP. Your link doesn't work. You can begin here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: yes!! because Palmcity.net host is behind a vpn, I just wanted to show you what I did.